# Dividing a Float Field by an Integer

Tags: jasper-reports

I am sure this has a simple answer, however it alludes me at the moment!  I am wanting to convert a float field in a *JasperReports* report by dividing by an integer (in fact converting hours to days):

```
$F{Average} / 24
```

This results in a blank result.  I have tried to use:

```
$F(Average).divide(java.math.BigInteger(24))
```

and similar, but get compilation errors.

Apologies if this is a bit simple, but it would be good to get some assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the new keyword:

```
$F(Average).divide(new java.math.BigDecimal(24, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
```